# Searching for name of a natural constant

Tags: forces

Everyone has heard something like this in school: The ant is the strongest animal because relating to its own weight it can lift the heaviest weights.

But as far as I know the strenght of a material does not scale with size.
Meaning an ant of the same material but scaled up to the size of a human would not be able to lift its own weight as many times as the small ant can.

Which natural force causes this behaviour?

Comment: "_Physics of scale_", maybe?  But, yeah, I think folks tend to say that a human-sized ant would be crushed under its own weight, much less able to carry anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes referred to as the *square-cube relation*, which in its simplest form tells us the following: the load-bearing cross-sectional area of for example a leg bone scales with the *square* of the bone's cross-sectional radius, but the weight of the animal possessing that leg scales with the *cube* of the radius of its body. This means large animals require disproportionately thick (and therefore heavy) legs, which become harder and harder to move as the animal gets scaled up bigger and bigger.

The opposite becomes true as you scale things *down* instead, which is why tiny animals can lift and carry things lots heavier than they are, without being crushed.

It is also the reason why you can beat this game and be big, if you can avoid gravity by living in a buoyant medium that supports your weight without requiring big bones: so we get whales on one end of the scale and ants on the other.

Comment: Thx for answering. Can we perhaps look a bit more down on the level of atoms and the forces between them? For example with two pieces of wood in space. A toothpick and a tree with 1000x the dimensions of the toothpick. Why can he toothpick resist a bending force that the tree cannot resist (scaled up x1000)? The weight of both objects are not relevant because they are floating in space. Only the material strength matters.